# Failing to deploy nestjs app on aws elastic beanstalk. Npm failed to install dependencies error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nestjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Nest app on aws eb but it fails and health turns to severe and then degraded. In the logs it says that npm failed to install dependencies that you defined in 'package.json'.
I've tried with increasing timeout from 10 to 25 minutes with no luck. Any ideas of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. test it locally if it works then try the following
2. check ur ec2 maybe its too small eg nano change it to micro
3. check if ur ec2 are in private subnet if so check if u have nat ,
   just log in to ec2 and ping google.com
4. check if ur container is EXPOSING port 80 if not expose it
5. double check ur logs especially init logs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).